# How to get own attributes object into itself

Tags: jquery, css

there!

I wanna center the div by horizontal.
Now I have to use Javascript + CSS. It looks like this

CSS:

```
div#block {
   left: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#block').css('margin-left', ($('#block').outerWidth()/2) + 'px');
```

Brobably, I can do like this:

```
div#block {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: self -50%;
}
```

Thank a lot for your help =)

Comment: Set the div to have "auto" left and right margins, and center-align the container?

Comment: whats your question, all of that will work and they will work better if it has a width - the self in the third one

Comment: I don't know width, because div's contents are different

Comment: I found solution, but It isn't good =( div#block {left: 50%; margin-left: -25%}. It won't work when you resize browser's window :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="blockparent"><div id="block"></div></div>

div#blockparent {
   width: 100%; /*or fixed width*/
}

div#block {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```